# Binary tree "get open list" SQL query

Tags: postgresql, join, recursive, tree

I have a node table that looks like this, plus it has an `inserted_at` column:

```
id        |  parent_id
----------+-----------
1         |  nil
2         |  1
3         |  1
4         |  2
5         |  2
6         |  3
7         |  4
8         |  5
9         |  6
10        |  3
```

It's a representation of a binary tree that looks like this:

```
             1
          /     \
        2         3
     /   \       /   \
    4    5      10    6
   /     /             \
  7     8               9
```

I'm trying to write a recursive SQL query that gets a list of nope nodes - nodes that have 1 or 2 open places below them - that is the list of nodes that aren't listed as a parent_id to other nodes 2 times.

This "open_list" would contain 4,5,10,6,7,8,9 because all those nodes have less than two children. So is this possible in SQL? One query that produces the "open list" of a binary tree.

Maybe I'd have to be a recursive CTE table using a WITH statment that some how has a join on itself ?

```
With recursive (
   select *
   join on self... recursive
)
select * from recursive
```

That's where my totally amateur intuition goes. Can someone who has a bit more experience guide me to the answer?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I think you don't need a recursive query, simply get those records that do not have two child records.

> ```
> select *
> from   mytable
> where  id not in(select   parent_id
>                  from     mytable
>                  group by parent_id
>                  having   count(*) > 1);
> ```
>
> ```
> id | parent_id
> -: | --------:
>  4 |         2
>  5 |         2
>  6 |         3
>  7 |         4
>  8 |         5
>  9 |         6
> 10 |         3
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5a4390e9ef4c4a882a5140400aa1f940)*

Comment: oh I was making that way harder than it needed to be! Thanks!